# Definition request: Radical of a Banach algebra

Tags: definition, banach-algebras

I am reading the definition of a semi-simple Banach algebra which is given as

> The Banach algebra $A$ having the property that Rad$(A)=\{0\}$ is called a *semi -simple Banach algebra*.

I can not, however, find a proper definition of what exactly the *radical* of a Banach algebra $A$ is. Can anybody please clarify what exactly it is by providing me with a nicely written definition?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this term refers to the [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical). This has several equivalent characterizations, so which one you take as the definition is to some extent a matter of taste.

Incidentally, in abstract algebra, rings with vanishing Jacobson radical are often called [semiprimitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimitive_ring) instead of semisimple, with semisimple being reserved for a much smaller class of rings (those whose modules are completely reducible).

Comment: People also call them $J$-semisimple, for obvious reasons. Semisimple rings are always $J$-semisimple, in fact the semisimple rings are those that are $J$-semisimple and artinian. I would guess because (the useful?) Banach algebras are rarely artinian, the $J$ is omited.